# Convert json into Formdata in react

Tags: javascript, python, json, reactjs, form-data

I have a data like below .I am trying to send data from React frontend to my Backend. I am trying to convert data and append in form . But I am getting ["object Object"]  for `dependents`. As you can see `dependents` data is LIST of object . Can anyone please help me to convert this `dependents`  array into FORMADATA

```
const data = {
    address: "test",
    bvn: "test",
    dependents: [
        {
            dob: null,
            email: "test@gmail.com",
            photo: [File],
            surname: "test"
        },
        {
            dob: null,
            email: "test@gmail.com",
            photo: [File],
            surname: "test"
        }
    ]
};
```

Here is my code

````
const formData = new FormData()
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        let value = data[key]
        if (value) {
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                let arr = new Array()
                for (let index = 0; index < value.length; index++) {
                    let formData2 = new FormData();
                    Object.keys(value[index]).forEach(key2 => {
                        let value2 = value[index][key2]
                        formData2.append(key2, value2)
                    })
                    arr.push(value[index])
                }
                formData.append('dependents', JSON.stringify(arr))
            } else {
                formData.append(key, value)
            }
        }
    ```
````